# ¿Por qué cuando instalo Gulp me crea en la carpeta node_modules con muchas otras carpetas?

Tags: nodejs, npm, gulp

Hola estoy usando Gulp y al momento de instalarlo me crea decenas de dependencias dentro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve viendo tutoriales en internet de como usar Gulp y cuando lo instalan en la carpeta node_modules solo aparece Gulp y las otras dependencias que se mandan a instalar.

¿Esto es normal?
En el archivo package.json solo llamo a Gulp.

Comment: Según tengo entendido, los módulos pueden usar otros módulos y se te instalan ahí. No deberías preocuparte.

Comment: Hola la carpeta node_modules contiene las paquetes que tu has instalado y ademas las dependencias de estos paquetes por eso es que llegas a ver mas carpetas a demás de los paquetes que tu instalaste dependiendo de la versión de npm 2.x o 3.x o posterior la organización de carpetas es un poco diferente te recomiendo actualizar a la versión mas reciente de npm, las cuales tiene un mejor manejo de dependencias, solo tienes que correr en tu terminal `npm install -g npm`